# 403 Forbidden on Fetch post request, but only with some Android Browser

Tags: android, node.js, express, fetch, cloudflare

I have different results (204 and 403) using fetch from Android default browser.

- A router.post(/page) is configured on express
- Express is using helmet
- A whatwg-fetch post request is sent by the browsers
- Two apps are running on the same machine with different domains (stage.domain.com and domain.com), they have same nginx config and .env for node (both have also NODE_ENV=production)
- Both environment are using cloudflare

On the stage.domain.com environment I'm ALWAYS getting 204 -> GOOD

On the domain.com environment I'm getting 403 for almost every Android default browsers.
More: with some android browser (SamsungBrowser/9.4) I'm getting 204 -> GOOD but only with beta version and incognito mode.

I did try to set the User-Agent header, but it is overwritten by the mobile browser.
I did also try to change "credentials" parameter to "same-origin", but it breaks other more requests.

Anyway, as I wrote: this is ALWAYS working under stage.domain.com

Here's my request:

```
fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  credentials: 'include',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type':'application/json',
    'Accept':'application/json',
    'Cache': 'no-cache',
    'X-CSRF-Token': formData._csrf
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(formData)
}).then(function (response) {...
```

I'm getting crazy on this 403. Knowing what changes in samsung browser between standard/incognito/beta may help.

It may be a Chromium issue, but why should it work on stage.domain.com then?

Thank you for any kind of reply :)

Comment: Does the 403 come with Cloudflare branding or not? Refer to this https://community.cloudflare.com/t/community-tip-fixing-error-403-forbidden/53308

Comment: Nope, cloudflare is passed, I find the 403 both in nginx and pm2 log. Thank you.